# Notebook BIOS cannot use some RAM sticks after hardware failure

Tags: memory, bios, motherboard

I have an Asus M515DA-EJ502T; Ryzen 3500u. Never made alterations in the system aside from dual-booting Linux.

Recently my the notebook motherboard was repaired due to a short circuit in a capacitor. The notebook would finally turn on again after repair, however there's now a problem with RAM.

It has 4GB soldered RAM, and a slot for a RAM stick (DDR4). I have a 8GB stick (don't know specifications) which came together with the notebook.

When the 8GB RAM is installed on the motherboard, BIOS only shows 4096MB (the soldered RAM), and Windows also shows:

> "Installed RAM 12.00 GB (3.45 GB usable)"

512mb gets reserved for Vega 8, same on Linux.
Also, the system only boots 1 or 2 times: if I restart, the notebook freezes on boot and I have to hold the power button to turn it off. Then I can only boot the system by doing an EC reset every time.

Without the RAM stick installed, the notebook works completely normal.

In the repair shop, we tested 2 other sticks: a DDR4 8GB 2666Mhz stick which had the exact same symptoms. And a DDR4 16GB 3200MHz stick which apparently worked normally

> "Installed RAM 20.00 GB (17.9 GB usable)"

##### So, what can I do/test before just buying the 16GB stick?

Comment: Seems a bit strange.  Could be a compatibility issue with the 8 Gb stick. If the 16 Gb stick works and is returnable, use that.

Comment: Get the 16 GB stick, and if it doesn't work, switch it with the one you tested and *you know does* work. There might be a question of ethics, but I'd let the owner know what you did, and that RAM does not wear out (unlike flash memory).